# Remove a wrong playlist to test explorer in visual studio 2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, playlist, test-explorer

I added a wrong playlist into test explorer, the error message shows up in output windows when compiling my test project every time. It says "Error reading playlist file 'E:*********.cs'.
There is an error in XML document (1, 1)."
And the the test Explorer it shows "Selected playlist is invalid. Fix the errors to see tests. See the output window Tests pane for more information"
I guess the playlist should be .xml file , and I just added a .cs file as .xml file. By the way, I don't need a playlist for my test, I just don't want to see that message anymore.

Thanks,guys

Comment: I am curious if you found a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 4):

in the while I have found the solution though I was looking for same issue.

1. Close solution
2. Locate your playlist where it is saved and then delete it, easy - isn't it? :)
3. Reopen your solution and re build your solution. Everything should be fine. The playlist should not appear anymore.

Find more at: http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-remove-wrong-playlist-from-test.html